# Why is my table broken in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have created some css tables. It works on everything but IE8?

```
<div class="main-table">
<div class="row">
    <a class="secondary-table" href="#">
        <div class="secondary-row">
            <div class="secondary-cell">
                $1000000000
            </div>
            <div class="secondary-cell">
                descrip<br /><span class="info">info</span>
            </div>
            <div class="secondary-cell" align="right">
                <button>View</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary-row">
            <div class="secondary-cell">
                info
            </div>
            <div class="secondary-cell">
            </div>
            <div class="secondary-cell" align="right">
                <button>View</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.main-table {
    display: table; 
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
    height: 700px;
    background: white;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}

.secondary-cell:first-child {
    width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.secondary-table {
    display: table;
    table-layout: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 100%;
}

a.secondary-table:hover {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.secondary-row {
    display: table-row;
}


@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

.secondary-row:last-child {
    display: none;
}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.secondary-row:first-child .secondary-cell:last-child {
    display: none;
} 

.info {
    display: none;
    }

}

.secondary-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 10px;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t9YaL/1/

Comment: `Why is my table broken in IE8?` Because IE8. Just kidding - how is it "broken"?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not just use `<table>` directly?

Comment: ^ THIS (@Renan). It is specifically the reason that so many developers are litteraly dropping support for that browser.

Comment: If you're showing tabular data, then you should be using tables, not some shady code. Most negativity about tables is directed to the fact that they are (mis)used too often as the layout of a site, rather than as an element to show information.

Comment: IE8 does not support media queries. [Check here.](http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries)

Comment: What Dai and Goldentoa11 said. "Tableless" design is so 2006 (or earlier, I think). You should never use tables for styling, but when it comes to **tabular data**, use tables no matter what.

Comment: @Dai I need to wrap some rows in links. So I can just wrap tr's with anchors?

Comment: @xckpd7 No. Instead put an `<a>` in each of your cells, and use CSS to make each anchor expand to fill its cell.

Comment: @Dai Won't work. I need there to be a "row" hover for each row.

Comment: @xckpd7 Then use `tr:hover` for a hover effect.

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You have put `<div>` elements inside `<a>` elements. The anchor element is an inline element, and can't contain block elements like divisions.</strike>

This is allowed in HTML5, which is why newer browsers allow it, but IE8 doesn't support HTML5.

Older browsers like IE8 will try to correct the code as best possible. That is usually done by either ending the anchor tag before the division, or move the division out of the anchor tag.

Forget that. The reason is simply that you have mixed in other elements in the table. A table consists of cells that are in rows that are in the table (and optionaly table header/body/footer around the rows). You can't have other elements around the cells or rows in the table, any other elements has to go inside the cells.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted as it is clearly correct

Comment: @Guffa - That's just not so. IE has supported `<div>` in `<a>` without breaking the anchor long before HTML5 and long before IE8. Firefox was pretty much the only browser that broke up the anchor before HTML5.

Comment: You are right, it's not the block elements that is the problem, it's the links in the table.